# How do I remove video noise & grain in iMovie '11?

Tags: imovie, video-editing, plugins

I'm attempting to remove some video noise/grain in iMovie 11 taken in low-light but haven't found a way to do this within iMovie itself. I've looked for plugins but the only ones I've found don't have free trials and I don't trust paying for software if I can't be assured it will work.

Is there a way to remove video noise/grain in iMovie?

Comment: Grainyness is caused by a high ISO; used in settings of low light. I'm not really sure that can be fixed. For future reference, use a higher exposure setting, not a higher ISO setting.

Comment: @daviesgeek You're right in saying that noise is a result of a high ISO, however I'm aware of that (I'm also a photographer) and noise/grain can be removed at least partly by comparing two neighboring frames and judging what of the resulting images is noise and what is actual data. I've seen stand-alone programs that do this for video, but iMovie doesn't seem to do this and so I'm looking for a plugin that adds this apparently missing functionality. :)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately [iMovie doesn't take plugins.](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3245310?start=0&tstart=0)

Best bet is external software OR Final Cut Pro 7 has numerous plugins that reduce noise and grain, but they are all very expensive.

Comment: I'd rather not spend that much on Final Cut Pro but iMovie does take plugins: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/815070?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Ah. Correction: iMovie 11 doesn't take plugins: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3245310?start=0&tstart=0